# Is there a more effecient way to check if value exists in rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of names `UniqueNames` and a Pandas DataFrame `NamesOverTime`, which has in each row a list of names. I want to obtain a series indicating if the name is included at a particular row/date. The following code works perfectly fine, but it seems quite slow. Any ideas how to improve perfomance?

```
for index, row in UniqueNames.iterrows():  
    IndSeries = (NamesOverTime==row['Name']).any(axis=1)
```

An example could be:

```
 UniqueNames = DataFrame({'Name': ('hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 
                        'hello4', 'ciao5')})
 NamesOverTime = DataFrame( {'1': ('hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4'), 
                             '2': ('hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', NaN), 
                             '3': ('hello3', 'hello1', 'ciao5', NaN)})

 NamesOverTime = NamesOverTime.transpose()
 NamesOverTime.index = pd.date_range('2015-05-31', periods=3, freq='M')
```

So names are of arbirtrary order in the dataframe.

My actual dataset is bigger in size, but not massiv. I have a set of around 4000 names and a Dataframe T=300 (rows) and N=3000 (columns)

EDIT: the expected output is a Pandas series object for each name contained in `UniqueNames`. The fastest I could get with your answer is something like this, but it is still approx. 3 times slower than the original version.

```
NamesOTStack = NamesOverTime.stack()
NamesOTStack = NamesOTStack.reset_index(1)

for index, row in UniqueNames.iterrows():
    temp = NamesOTStack[NamesOTStack.loc[:,0]==row['Name']] 
    IndSeries = pd.Series(NamesOverTime.index.isin(temp.index))
    IndSeries.index = NamesOverTime.index
```

`IndSeries` for `'hello4'` looks like:

```
IndSeries
Out[16]: 
2015-05-31     True
2015-06-30    False
2015-07-31    False
Freq: M, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you post raw input data, a representative df and sample names you want to match as it matters

Comment: Please update the question with that information.

Comment: Please print an example of ```IndSeries```.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You've changed the structure of your input which is really important and which demands a different answer. Anyway, here goes. I've created a dataframe with 3000 names randomly selected from 4000 without replacement in each of 365 rows.

```
name_time_pairs = NamesOverTime.unstack().dropna()
name_time_pairs.name = 'name'
name_time_pairs = name_time_pairs.reset_index().iloc[:, 1:]
name_time_pairs['value'] = True

In [104]: name_time_pairs[:2]

Out[104]:
    time        name    value
0   2015-01-01  ypac    True
1   2015-01-02  fjnq    True
```

So far we have a DataFrame with a row for each time-name pair and a column containing `True`, 1,098,000 rows in total. Now all that needs to be done is pivot the table and fill the null values with `False`.

```
result = name_time_pairs.pivot(index='time', columns='name', values='value').fillna(False)
```

If you can show this is slower than looping through 4000 names and scanning the the original data frame in each loop is slower I'll eat my hat. I have it at 100 times faster.

You should break this solution down to see how each step works as it is quite terse and I've already spent too much time answering this question. It's also quite convoluted as the structure of the result, I think, is unusual. Essentially what you have is a set of time-name pairs. Storing these as index and column labels of a Dataframe of booleans seems to me to be inefficient and perhaps it could be done another way.

Comment: The problem is I cannot iterater over sets, hence I would need to create in each iteration a list or set from `row['Name']`. (I don't want to evaluate the entire set at once,  i want for each name one series. If I timeit `(NamesOverTime==row['Name']).any(axis=1)` is approx. ten time faster than `NameSeries.isin(unique_names).unstack().any(axis=1)`

Comment: I don't really follow you. According to the data you provided, there is just one name in each row in the 'Name' column. When you say my method is 10 times slower, you seems to be comparing that to a single iteration in your loop but you have 4000 iterations. I think you need to give more a bigger sample and provide expected input/output

Comment: You can get that in your example just by calling```NamesOverTime.notnull()```. In the example, row 1 contains 'hello1' only, row 2 contains hello 2 etc. The only exception is a NaN (which is you give as a string rather than the actual ```NaN``` object). Is that actually your use case or is it more complicated? Please provide a bigger data frame with the actual names, column names and index values.

Comment: I've updated the example. I should have been more explicit. the words are of arbitrary order, so I cannot simply utilized `notnull()`, which would have been a nice way out. The actual names set is too big, but the names do not follow any pattern. Columns names are simply 1,...,N, the index consists of end of month dates...

Comment: Yeah, and where are the times? Your df is called NameOverTimes but it doesn't contain either!! Are they represented by 1, 2, 3 here?

Comment: I have edited the question in responds to your edit.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort! However, the last line raises an error `"cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`  I will try to solve the error the next days. PS: I know at this stage it appears not very effecient, it will mapped later into a table with  almost no redundancy....

Comment: Then there must be duplicate time/name pairs, i.e. at least one name occurs more than once at least one time. I've edited the question to remove duplicate time/name pairs and also to remove ```nan```-time pairs

Comment: It was indeed the nan causing the problem. The dataframe has only unqiue date-value pairs, hence we can drop. `.drop_duplicates()` in the first line. Unfortunately, the perfomance falls short of the benchmark by a factor of approx. 3.